# JavaFX: use ListView.edit(int itemIndex) with in the onEditCommit function

Tags: java, listview, javafx

I am trying to create an editable list view in javaFX that is easy to use for the user. To do this I have used the on edit commit function. It was generally very good at doing what I wanted it to do however I ran into one problem. Every time the user edits the last item I want it to make another Item and start editing that. It would seem as though this is trivial however I have run into problems running the dit function from with in the `setOnEditCommit`function. Here is my code:

```
 personList.setOnEditCommit(new EventHandler<ListView.EditEvent<String>>() {
        @Override
        public void handle(ListView.EditEvent<String> t) {
            personList.getItems().set(t.getIndex(), t.getNewValue());

            if(personList.getSelectionModel().getSelectedIndices().contains(personList.getItems().size()-1)) {
                int personNumber = personList.getItems().size() + 1;
                personList.getItems().add("person " + personNumber);
                personList.edit(personList.getItems().size()-1); //the line that is not working.
            }
        }

    });
```

note: personlist is a ListView

Is there anyway to run the edit function from with in the set on `setOnEditCommit`. Thanks.

Comment: looks like a bug to me: the event sequence is weird - the moment you modify the data (f.i. by setting the new item), there's an intermediate cancelEvent ... editing virtual controls is really, really broken ...

Comment: the reason could be the "fix" to https://bugs.openjdk.java.net/browse/JDK-8094887 - edits are cancelled on any change to the underlying data

Answer (score 1):

The base problem is that the re-edit by the commitHandler is cancelled. There are many (and intricate) paths that can trigger a cancel, one of them seems to be the "fix" to [JDK-8094887](https://bugs.openjdk.java.net/browse/JDK-8094887) which rather rudely cancels any edit on changes to the data.

But that can't be the whole story because the cancel received after the re-edit is triggered during cell configuration, roughly:

```
indexedCell.updateIndex(index)
-> listCell.indexChanged(oldIndex, newIndex)
-> listCell.updateFocus()
-> node.setFocused(xx)  //for some reason xx is false
-> cell.focusedListener 
-> cancelEdit()
```

Running the example below, editing the single item, pressing ENTER produces the output:

```
edit start: 0   // start edit on last row
edit commit: 0  // commit the edit by items.set(...)
edit cancel: -1 // cancel triggered by modification
edit start: 1   // re-edit the added item
edit cancel: -1 // cancel triggered by cell config
```

The only way out I could come up with is very brittle: start the re-edit as you do, then also start a timer that "waits" until all internal configuration is done and edit again. Nothing we want to do in production code, obviously ;)

```
import javafx.animation.KeyFrame;
import javafx.animation.Timeline;
import javafx.application.Application;
import javafx.collections.FXCollections;
import javafx.scene.Scene;
import javafx.scene.control.ListView;
import javafx.scene.control.cell.TextFieldListCell;
import javafx.scene.layout.BorderPane;
import javafx.stage.Stage;
import javafx.util.Duration;

/**
 * Trying to add item/start edit on new item in commitHandler:
 * https://stackoverflow.com/q/46047134/203657
 * 
 * one last try: use timer to start editing some time later ..
 */
public class ListViewAutoEditInHandler extends Application {

    private ListView<String> simpleList;
    private int expectedEditIndex = -1;
    private Timeline editTimer;

    /**
     * Callback for editTimer. Implemented to scroll to and force
     * edit of cell at expectedEditIndex.
     */
    private void checkEdit() {
        if (expectedEditIndex < 0) return;
        if (expectedEditIndex == simpleList.getEditingIndex()) {
            expectedEditIndex = -1;
            return;
        }
        int index = expectedEditIndex;
        expectedEditIndex = -1;
        simpleList.scrollTo(index);
        simpleList.edit(index);
    }

    @Override
    public void start(Stage primaryStage) {
        editTimer = new Timeline(new KeyFrame(Duration.millis(100), ae -> checkEdit() ));
        simpleList = new ListView<>(FXCollections.observableArrayList("Item1"));
        simpleList.setEditable(true);

        simpleList.setCellFactory(TextFieldListCell.forListView());

        simpleList.setOnEditStart(t -> p("edit start: " + t.getIndex()));
        simpleList.setOnEditCancel(t -> p("edit cancel: " + t.getIndex()));
        simpleList.setOnEditCommit(t -> {
            p("edit commit: " + t.getIndex());
            // any modification of the items will trigger a cancel
            simpleList.getItems().set(t.getIndex(), t.getNewValue());
            //  p("editing? " + simpleList.getEditingIndex());
            if (t.getIndex() == simpleList.getItems().size() - 1) {
                expectedEditIndex = t.getIndex() + 1;
                simpleList.getItems().add("newItem");
                simpleList.getSelectionModel().select(expectedEditIndex);
                simpleList.edit(expectedEditIndex);
                // ... so we start a timer to force
                // uncomment for a brittle solution ;)
                // editTimer.playFromStart();
            } else {
                // reset .. a bit paranoid here ;)
                expectedEditIndex = -1;
                editTimer.stop();
            }

        });


        BorderPane root = new BorderPane(simpleList);
        Scene scene = new Scene(root, 300, 250);

        primaryStage.setTitle("Hello World!");
        primaryStage.setScene(scene);
        primaryStage.show();
    }

    private static void p(String t) {
        System.out.println(t);
    }
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        launch(args);
    }
}
```

Comment: thanks, I am doing this in production however, so... is this an error that should happen or something that could be reported?

Comment: that's the question ;) Receiving the cancel after commit is clearly a bug, I think (happens with the default handler as well, reported as https://bugs.openjdk.java.net/browse/JDK-8187307) As to starting another edit in the commitHandler .. I'm not so certain: the system probably needs to complete its state transition from editing to not-editing  before being able to reliably start another cycle. On the other hand: the requirement is simple enough and I can't see how/where to implement it.